# TypeORM not returning generated uuid value

Tags: typeorm

I am trying to insert a value into a table and then retrieve the UUID that is auto generated, but the return only returns the values that I inserted.

```
export class Associations {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'id', nullable: false })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'uuid', nullable: false, type: 'uuid' })
  uuid: string;

  @Column({ name: 'source_uuid', nullable: false, type: 'uuid' })
  source_uuid: string;

  @Column({ name: 'target_uuid', nullable: false, type: 'uuid' })
  target_uuid: string;

  @Column({ name: 'is_active', nullable: false })
  is_active: boolean;
}
```

```
async saveAssociation(associationBody) {
    let association: Associations = new Associations();
    association.source_uuid = associationBody.associationSourceEntityId;
    association.target_uuid = associationBody.associationAssociatedEntityId;
    association.is_active = true;
    const savedAssociation = await       dataSourceContainer.getDataSource().getRepository(Associations).save(association)
    return savedAssociation
```

The return value looks like this

```
  source_uuid: '89d1234c-5dc9-4f5d-9abd-7755b9fe766b',
  target_uuid: '9cbdacda-1d33-400f-b777-3ae1fde66f20',
  is_active: true
```

But when I look in the database the values are all there

```
id: 28
uuid: fb0dea42-e24a-4c28-9bd8-165675ce3891 
source_uuid: 89d1234c-5dc9-4f5d-9abd-7755b9fe766b
target_uuid: 9cbdacda-1d33-400f-b777-3ae1fde66f20
is_active: true
```

I've tried inserting the values directly into save() as an object but that did not work.